# Ajax function only displaying one div at a time, PHP, AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a working ajax function where when its called by the click of a button, it gets the time and display it to the screen, waits five seconds, and does it again. However, only 1 div at the max is displayed at the same time. I want to display both divs at the same time when they're both clicked, but it just doesn't display both at the same time. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code below:

**test1.php**

```
#output1 {
border: 1px solid green;
}
#output2 {
border: 1px solid red;
}

<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'name1' value = 'Reset' onclick = 'timeoutAjax(\"test2.php\",\"input\",\"name1\",\"output1\",\"5000\")'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'name2' value = 'Reset' onclick = 'timeoutAjax(\"test2.php\",\"input\",\"name2\",\"output2\",\"5000\")'>";

echo "<div id = 'output1'/>";
echo "<div id = 'output2'/>";

?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

$time = date('H:i:s A');
echo $time;

?>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

// prepare some storage for the xhr and timeout
var queued, xhr;

function timeoutAjax(url, type, theName, id, timeout) {
    // abort pending calls
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.abort();
    }
    // abort queued calls
    clearTimeout(queued);

    // make the call
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            select: $(type + '[name=' + theName + ']').val()
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;
            // queue a new call
            queued = setTimeout(function () {
                timeoutAjax(url, type, theName, id, timeout);
            }, timeout);
        }

    });

}

</script>
```

Comment: You have a single timeout and a single xhr - how should this run concurrently?

Comment: @EugenRieck Any code example would be greatly appreciated, and if it works, it'll be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: you have a global `xhr` variable and it gets updated on each timeout refresh (or submit click for that matter) and if the variable is currently in use is aborts the other.

Comment: just get rid of the whole `xhr` thing and make your error function as simple as `error: function (error) {` since you're only using the variable `error` in there anyway.

Comment: @iam-decoder How do I make it so that xhr variable is independent to each different ajax call for different buttons, but keep the aspect that let it get update on each timeout refresh or submit click?

Comment: @developerwjk I kind of need the xhr thing so the ajax calls doesn't pile up if the user keep clicking the submit button over and over again. If they click the submit button 10 times, there would be 10 ajax functions out there if I don't use the xhr thing.

Comment: disable the button until the first one finished, and renable it in the success method

Comment: or keep a counter and don't allow another to fire if the counter hasn't decremented below X

Comment: @developerwjk About that...I kind of want the user to be able to refresh the ajax function when they click the submit button. So if they click the submit button again, it'll show the new current time, before waiting 5 seconds after that to show the time after that. Instead of just not letting them click the button, I kind of want it so that they CAN click the button, but without the ajax functions piling up if they keep clicking it, and thus the xhr thing. But also, I want it so they can click more than 1 button at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your scripts to be like this:

**test.php:**

```
<style>
#output1 {
    min-height: 20px;
border: 1px solid green;
}
#output2 {
    min-height: 20px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'name1' value = 'Reset' onclick = 'timeoutAjax(\"test2.php\",\"input\",\"name1\",\"output1\",\"5000\")'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'name2' value = 'Reset' onclick = 'timeoutAjax(\"test2.php\",\"input\",\"name2\",\"output2\",\"5000\")'>";

echo "<div id = 'output1'></div>";
echo "<div id = 'output2'></div>";

?>
```

**test2.php:**

```
<?php

$time = date('H:i:s A');
echo $time;

?>
```

**ajax.php:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var queues = {};
function timeoutAjax(url, type, theName, id, timeout) {
    clearInterval(queues[theName]);
    // make the call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            select: $(type + '[name=' + theName + ']').val()
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;
            // queue a new call
            queues[theName] = setInterval(function () {
                timeoutAjax(url, type, theName, id, timeout);
            }, timeout);
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('input[name="'+theName+'"]').prop("disabled",false);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('input[name="'+theName+'"]').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried the code above. The ajax function call piles up again and again when the user click the button again and again. So if the user clicks the button 5 times, there are 5 ajax function calls out there.

Comment: For example, if the user clicks one time at 3:00:00, and one time at 3:00:05, there would be a timeout call at 3:00:10, AND 3:00:15, and so on and so forth.

Comment: That's if the timeout is at 10 seconds ^^^

Comment: If the timeout is at 5 seconds it would be something like this: if the user clicks one time at 3:00:00, and one time at 3:00:02, there would be a timeout call at 3:00:05, AND 3:00:07, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Okay. I got to admit. This is perfect. You're brilliant. :)